# Can I enter UK with a permanent EU Residence Permit (Ukrainian citizen)?

Tags: visas, uk, england, residence-permits

I am a Ukrainian citizen living in Austria for 15 years. I own a permanent EU Residence Permit which gives me the same rights as to an EU citizen. Can I enter the UK without a visa? The gov.uk site is not helpful on that matter.

Comment: Note that there is no such thing as EU Permanent Residence Permit, and no permanent residence permit issued by EU member states give you the same rights as an EU citizen.

Comment: For sure, there is such thing as a "Daueraufenthalt - EU" (in Austria) which is granted unlimitedly and I only re-new the card every 5 years. 
But well, I must have missunderstood it all my life then that I do not have the same rights as an EU citizen...

Comment: I don't think that was the intent for travel outside the Schengen area, though I could be mistaken.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy there is such a thing, though the official term in English is "long-term residence" rather than "permanent residence."  You are correct that the rights are somewhat less than those accruing to EU citizens.  See https://home-affairs.ec.europa.eu/policies/migration-and-asylum/legal-migration-and-integration/long-term-residents_en  Among other differences, Denmark and Ireland (and formerly the UK) have opted out of the relevant directive.

Comment: For EU questions it might be good if we encouraged people to include the name of their visa/permit in the language it was issued as well, as English language translations don't always match exactly. Google translate is trying to sell me "Fiktionsbescheinigung" as "fiction certificate" rather than the "preliminary residence permit" it actually is.

Comment: @phoog Sure, the problem is that people often misunderstand what permit do they have and we cannot really guess what they have, specially in this case where even additional rights were assumed.

Comment: @Olesya For example EU citizens have freedom of movement, you do not, you cannot just move to Ireland for example and work there, while EU citizens can. You need additional permits.

Answer (score 7):

No; UK isn't in the EU and Ukrainian citizens are not eligible for visa-free entry to the UK. The permanent EU Resident permit has no effect here. See https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/ukraine/tourism/no

You may have options under https://www.gov.uk/guidance/support-for-family-members-of-british-nationals-in-ukraine-and-ukrainian-nationals-in-ukraine-and-the-uk though.

Comment: Yeah ofc I checked that link, and I was irritated by the fact there there is no space to choose the option that one might have a residence permit EU. So probably they are really not interested in it. For them, I am and stay Ukrainian citizen.

Comment: "probably they are really not interested in it" - correct. I think this was also the case when the UK was in the EU - it all boils down to them never being part of the Schengen zone.

I think this is also the case for Ireland (doesn't apply to you because Ireland, unlike the UK, provides visa-free access to Ukrainians by default).

Comment: I think that if you wanted to TRANSIT the UK on a connecting flight, then your EU residence status would allow you to do this without the normally-required visa. That's the only advantage the EU residency gives you. Obviously you would still need the required permission to enter your final destination.

Comment: @Leaderboard Technically, it has to do with the United Kingdom and Ireland having the right to opt-out from policies developed under the “area of freedom, security and justice” (in the case of Ireland mostly to allow them to maintain the common travel area with the UK). This is broader and separate from the Schengen area which started as a project from a handful of EU countries. Denmark negotiated somewhat similar but distinct opt-outs even if they did join the Schengen area on an intergovernmental basis (i.e. without behind bound to do it under EU law).